# Can multiple async methods updating same record can create row lock issue

Tags: apex, asynchronous, locking

Does multiple asynchronous process like Queueable, future etc running concurrently that are updating same record create row lock issues.

We are facing row lock issues in async transactions that updates same record (same record ID) and we doubt that multiple async transaction that we are doing is the main cause

So, does multiple different async transaction can create row lock issues on same record?

Thanks for the answer in advance!

Comment: By definition - yes; think of two users interacting with the same record on separate computers -- they are separate transactions; async transactions are still transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, multiple transactions locking the same record can cause locking issues. Also note that locking child records also lock the parent. For example, two asynchronous updates to separate contacts on the same account will block one of the updates until the other completes. Always lock parent records before child records to [avoid deadlocks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_deadlocks.htm).

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox!  Wanted to mention we have not locked the record  ( we haven't used FOR UPDATE), we are only doing DML. Does salesforce have OOB mechanism to lock?

Comment: @sfdeveloper Initiating a DML operation automatically locks a record and its parent. However, the lock timeout is *much* smaller if you do this. I strongly recommend locking the records with FOR UPDATE for a better experience.